# Webmatrix PHP starter site + Google Charts

Tags: php, ajax, json, google-visualization, webmatrix

I am working on creating my first dashboard site to dynamically display MySQL data to various users. For some context, I am using the Webmatrix PHP starter site and am having trouble figuring out how to query the data into .json format to be read by the Google Charts API. I've successfully hard coded an array to pass to the Google Chart with .ajax, but am having trouble with building the array from an SQL query.

I've searched all week for a solution and haven't found one yet.

My current code is below and returns the "Table has no columns" error.

-Query and parse to .json (Unsolved)

```
<?php 
    // -----> Query MySQL and parse into JSON below. <------

    // write your SQL query here (you may use parameters from $_GET or $_POST if you need them)

    require_once ("Includes/session.php");
    require_once ("Includes/simplecms-config.php");
    require_once ("Includes/connectDB.php");
    include("Includes/header.php");

    $recId = null;
    $projid = null;
    $hours = null;

    $recId = $_GET['id'];
    $projid = $_GET['projid'];
    $hours = $_GET['hours'];
    $query = "SELECT projid, hours FROM hours WHERE id = ?";
    $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('d', $recId);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();

    $rows = array();
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
                        array('label' => 'projid', 'type' => 'string'),
                        array('label' => 'hours', 'type' => 'number')
                     );

    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {
       $temp = array();

       // The following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
       $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['projid']); 

       // Values of the each slice
       $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['hours']); 
       $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;

    // convert data into JSON format
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    //echo $jsonTable;
```

?>

-Load .ajax and draw chart (Solved)

```
<?php 
     include("Includes/header.php");
     include("Includes/charts/piecharthours.php");
     include("Includes/charts/linechart.php");
?>

 <html>
     <head>
        <!--Load the AJAX API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "getDatahours.php",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, { width: 400, height: 240 });

            setInterval(drawChart, 500);
       }

   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
   <div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

-Console Output

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON string: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <link href="/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Styles/Sitemenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Styles/site2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <body>
        <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">
                        <a href="/index.php" class="uclogo">UC Logo</a>
                        <a href="/index.php">UC</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        <ul id="login">
                        <li><a href="/logoff.php">Sign out</a></li>
<li><a href="/addpage.php">Add</a></li>
<li><a href="/selectpagetoedit.php">Edit</a></li>
<li><a href="/deletepage.php">Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="welcomeMessage">Welcome, <strong>ID</strong></div>
                    </section>
                </div>

                <div class="clear-fix"></div>
            </div>

                <section class="navigation" data-role="navbar">
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/index.php">Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/projects.php">Projects</a>
                                <ul>
                                <li><a href="/page.php?pageid=1">P4</a></li>
<li><a href="/page.php?pageid=2">P1</a></li>
<li><a href="/page.php?pageid=3">P2</a></li>
<li><a href="/page.php?pageid=4">P3</a></li>
                                </ul>

                            <li><a href="/resources.php">Resources</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/reporting.php">Reporting</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/help.php">Help</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </section>
        </header> format+en,default,corechart.I.js:60
Uncaught Error: Container is not defined example.php:6
Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON string: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <link href="/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Styles/Sitemenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Styles/site2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <body>
        <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">
                        <a href="/index.php" class="uclogo">UC Logo</a>
                        <a href="/index.php">UC</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        <ul id="login">
                        <li><a href="/logoff.php">Sign out</a></li>
<li><a href="/addpage.php">Add</a></li>
<li><a href="/selectpagetoedit.php">Edit</a></li>
<li><a href="/deletepage.php">Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="welcomeMessage">Welcome, <strong>ID</strong></div>
                    </section>
                </div>

                <div class="clear-fix"></div>
            </div>

                <section class="navigation" data-role="navbar">
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/index.php">Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/projects.php">Projects</a>
                                <ul>
                                <li><a href="/page.php?pageid=1">P4</a></li>
<li><a href="/page.php?pageid=2">P1</a></li>
<li><a href="/page.php?pageid=3">P2</a></li>
<li><a href="/page.php?pageid=4">P3</a></li>
                                </ul>

                            <li><a href="/resources.php">Resources</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/reporting.php">Reporting</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/help.php">Help</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </section>
        </header>
```

Comment: Add the line `console.log(jsonData);` to your drawChart function, open the page in Chrome, view the developer's console, and paste the output here, so I can see what your server-side code is producing.

Comment: @asgallant The console output is added to the question.

Comment: Your `getDatahours.php` script is not returning the JSON for your DataTable - it is returning an HTML page.  You need to either point the AJAX call to the correct script or fix whatever is causing your PHP script to output HTML instead of JSON.

Comment: @asgallant As stated in my question, the AJAX call is pointed to the correct script which I've already tested using a manually created JSON file. The question I have is I am unable to successfully generate the JSON file from MySQL with the PHP script in the first code block above.

Comment: If the output of your `console.log(jsonData);` call matches what you posted above, then HTML is being injected somewhere in your `getDataHours.php` script, which is causing the json translation to fail.  You need to figure out why that is happening and fix it.